# Догонит ли один процесс другого?

Tags: java, процесс

Я запускаю два процесса с разными приоритетами и жду когда значение в одном догонит - в другом. Почему приоритет процессов так важен в многопоточной архитектуре, если процессы независимо выполняются для разных ядер? Зачем им спорить за ресурсы процессора? почему  они не могут полностью параллельно выполняться?

```
  public class ScheduleThreads
 {
static Counter low;
static Counter high;

public static void main(String[] argv) throws InterruptedException
{
    low=new Counter(200);
    high=new Counter(0);
    low.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    high.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    System.out.println("high priority is "+high.getPriority());
    System.out.println("low  priority is "+low.getPriority());

    low.start();
    high.start();

    int diff=low.getCount() - high.getCount();
    while(high.getCount()<low.getCount())
    {
        System.out.println("high : " + high.getCount() + "  low: " + low.getCount());
        if(low.getCount() - high.getCount() < diff)
        {
            diff = low.getCount() - high.getCount();
            low.suspend();
            high.suspend();
            System.out.println("difference is : " + diff );
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            low.resume();
            high.resume();

        }
    }

    low.stop();
    high.stop();

}
}
```

Класс, процессов гонщиков:

```
public class Counter extends Thread
  {
int Count;

public Counter()
{
    Count=0;
}

public Counter(int x)
{
    Count=x;
}

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Count++;
        try {
            sleep(10);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
}

public int getCount()
{
    return Count;
}
```

}

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что процесс/поток выполняется на каком-то фиксированном ядре? У вас в системе сотни процессов, все они время от времени получают небольшую долю процессорного времени на каком-то из ядер. Стратегия «закрепить одно ядро за одним процессом/потоком» могла бы работать, если бы у вас в системе количество процессов было бы не больше количества ядер.

Comment: есть ещё много ресурсов, о которых нужно не забывать. К примеру, оперативная память, кеш, hdd, сеть. А делить то их процессам также нужно. Очень редко бывают задачи, которые нагружают только процессор. К тому же, даже ядра внутри процессора не являются абсолютно независимыми.

Comment: @voipp, и какой у Вас результат?

В конце-концов high догоняет low и программа останавливается?

--

IMHO этого не произойдет из-за sleep(10) в run(). По сути оба потока будут выполняться синхронными шагами. Увеличил Count и уснул на 10 мсек., передав управление другому, который делает то же самое действие. Так они и будут почти все время спать.

Comment: А вы юзаете -XX:+UseThreadPriorities ? Без нее вроде не работают приоритеты (И вроде еще под root правами). Как по мне, в многопоточной среде, ориентированной не на реал-тайм обработку, лучше без них (приоритетов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного перефразирую комментарий [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd).  
Существуют процессы вне вашей программы. У этих процессов тоже есть приоритет. И они тоже "жрут" ресурсы вашей системы(конкретно - процессорное время). Рассмотрим пример системы с 2 ядрами. К примеру в системе кроме ваших процессов, еще 50 процессов с разным приоритетом. В зависимости от их приоритета им чаще выделяется процессорное время. Тут запускается ваша программа, добавляя еще 2 процесса с разным приоритетом. Система начинает выделять процессорное время и вашим процессам. А так, как кроме них на проц. время претендуют еще полсотни процессов, то выделяет она, естественно, не абсолютно все процессорное время. То есть, таким образом, процессу с большим приоритетом выделяется больше времени. Ваши потоки выполнялись бы с одинаковой скоростью только в том случае, если бы у вас хватало ядер на каждый поток.